# Button Doesn't Cover Whole Line in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

The `btn-block` style that I use in Bootstrap for the button to occupy the entire line is not applied. What should I do?

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably trying to use a feature in Bootstrap 5 that used to be in Bootstrap 4. If you are using Bootstrap 5, use the following code to render a button that covers the entire row:

```html
<div class="d-grid gap-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/) for the button styles used in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

In `Bootstrap5`, **dropped** `.btn-block` for utilities. Instead of using `.btn-block` on the `.btn`, wrap your buttons with `.d-grid` and a `.gap-*` utility to space them as needed.

```
<div class="d-grid gap-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

`d-grid` means `display: grid` and `gap-2`, this can save on having to add margin utilities to individual grid items (children of a `display: grid` container).

[This link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons) is a description of this example, and for more information about `gap-*` you can read [this article](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#gap).

Read more about changes in `Bootstrap5` in [this link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities) ( especially in your case, read [Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#buttons) ).

Good luck.

Comment: This is my pleasure